# Largest and smallest eigenvalue of $AB-BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices such that the largest eigenvalue of $AB-BA$ is positive. Then smallest eigenvalue of $AB-BA$

(a) must be positive

(b) must be negative

(c) must be $0$

(d) is none of the above

Source: ISI Qror 2021, 18th July exam

I think the answer should be (b) as a spectrum of eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ is the same.

So, if the largest eigenvalue of $AB-BA$ is $a-b$ then the smallest must be $b-a$. Please verify if it is correct

Comment: Since the four answer options are mutually exclusive, it would be enough to pick _one_ pair of $A,B$ that satisfy the assumption, and see which of the cases is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer $(b)$ is correct, but your explanation isn't too clear. Indeed we have $\sigma(AB) = \sigma(BA)$ but it doesn't imply $\sigma(AB-BA) = \{0\}$ or something like that.

It is simpler to notice that trace of $AB-BA$ is $0$. Since the trace is sum of eigenvalues, the smallest eigenvalue has to be negative.

Of course, you should also assume that all eigenvalues are real or something like that so that the terms "largest" and "smallest" make sense.